# date('G') function in php returns the wrong hour?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

So in my php coursework, one of the features inside my scheduling date system is comparing the value of the current time with the value of a time string from a database.
I get the current time value using the php date('G') function, which should return a 24 hour format, as follows:

```
  $hr = date('G');
```

(^that is the problem area)

```
  $day = date('d');
  $month = date('m');
  $year = date('Y');
  // Timezones
  }
  $wholeCurrentTime = $hr + ($day * 100) + ($month * 10000) + ($year * 1000000);
  echo $wholeCurrentTime;
```

However, the variable, $hr always returns the wrong time.

For example when it is **18pm** and I get the value, date('G'), it *should* return the value, **18**. But instead, it returns an hour ahead, in this case ***19***. My hypothesis is that the date function is stuck in GMT+1, when the area I am testing this in is GMT + 0 (until late March, when it returns to GMT + 1).

Question: Is this a bug with php, or do I need to add extra steps to determine the correct timezone?

Comment: What are the timezone settings on the server where PHP is running? Or at least, what is the current time on the server? Presumably you can check it another way, outside PHP

Comment: `echo date_default_timezone_get();` or `echo ini_get('date.timezone');`

Comment: Use DateTime objects and explicitly define the desired timezone in the constructor. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php